# How to Export my results to an excel sheet

Tags: export, excel

[image]I have a nonlinear equation in single variable( $x \tan(x)=5$ ) and it have an infinite number of roots , I got some of them and I want to add them in a table this is my code
please, tell me how to do this?

```
(* In[1]:= *) Reduce[x Tan[x] == 5 && 0 <= x <= 100, x]
```

then I used a `ToRule` to convert the `||` to

```
(* In[2]:= *) ToRules[Out[1]]
```

then I used export to export all roots to excel sheet but i got failed

```
Export["myfile.xls", Out[2]]
```

> Export::noelem: `{x->Root[{-5+#1 Tan[Slot[<<1>>]]&,4.0335677903399816532}]}` is not a valid set of export elements for the XLS format.

```
(* Out[3] = $Failed *)
```

Comment: "this is my code" - where?

Comment: Reduce[x Tan[x] == 5 && 0 <= x <= 100, x]

Comment: n = ToRules[Out[53]]

Comment: [Edit your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/221475/edit) to include this information, instead of leaving it in comments.

Comment: now you can see my code

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code text (as you've done in the comment), rather than the screenshot of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the conversion of `Sequence` into the `List` can be done easy:

```
   a=ToRules@Reduce[x Tan[x] == 5 && 0 <= x <= 100, x];
   b=x /. List[a];
   Export["file.xlsx", b]
```

The `Export` gives you an Excel file with the desired column of numbers

Comment: Thank you very much , you did it

Answer (score 6):

I think you probably want to use NSolve instead of Reduce.

```
roots = x /. NSolve[x Tan[x] == 5 && 0 <= x <= 100, x]
Export["outfile.xls", roots]
```

This will produce a column of 32 roots, which I think is what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much , you did it